# How to scale raphael.svg

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I have this **http://jsfiddle.net/bve42/3/**

I want to scale the svg as width -> 150% and height -> 150%

I read documentation of Raphael how to `scale` the canvas, but couldn't succeed. Does anyone know how to scale raphael.svg? I tried `paper.for.each` too, but didn't work either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you specifically need to accomplish this with Raphael? I just applied a CSS transform to scale it. See this fiddle please: http://jsfiddle.net/sArVy/

```
#rsr {
width: 250px;
transform:scale(1.5,1.5);
-ms-transform:scale(1.5,1.5);
-webkit-transform:scale(1.5,1.5);
}

#rsr:active {
transform: rotate(90deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```